# Missing tag badges

Tags: support, tags, badges

Tags "[etiquette](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette)", "[time-control](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-control)" and "[titles](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles)" don't appear to be available for tag badges.

According to the [Help Center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/badges) for bronze tag badges:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

However when I look at [my tags](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/4418/brian-towers?tab=tags) in my profile I see that for "etiquette" I have a score of 270 for 21 non-wiki answers, for "titles" I have a score of 156 for 21 non-wiki answers (+ 3 non-wiki questions) and for "time-control" I have a score of 156 for 21 non-wiki answers (+ 2 non-wiki questions) but no badges for these tags.

Furthermore if I go onto my profile and try to "Select your next badge" by clicking on the wheel next to "Next tag badge" these tags are not available in the lists presented. If I try and use the "Search for a badge" function it doesn't find any of these three tags.

It's as if these tags exist for questions but not for badges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have to be at least 100 questions with a given tag for tag badges to be available. None of those tags have 100 or more questions yet.

This is stated in the sidebar on this [Badges help page](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze)

Comment: Thanks. That looks like a drop-off in the help center as there is no mention of this in the badges section. In fact I can't find it mentioned in the help center at all.

Comment: @BrianTowers it's kind of buried. I added a link to where it can be found. I only knew about the requirements from a similar discussion on Puzzling Meta.